# Made For iPhone program specifics

Tags: iphone, ios, mfi

I have to develop a wireless adapter to fit into a medical device and an associated iPhone application.

I would be grateful if I can get to know the format in which I need to present them the project plan to get MFI certification for my device/adapter whichever is applicable.

How long is it going to take?  I have already posted a query to wwmarcom@apple.com, but they havent replied even after 5 days.

From your experience, are they supportive enough to get back to our queries in time once we enter into MFI program paying the required fee?

Answer (score 0):

You have to be in the MFI program.  If you are not I doubt that you are going to get any meaningful support.  Once you are in MFI you'll have a direct point of contact to help, advise and guide you through.  My experience, having been in the MFI program for over a year, has been nothing but positive.  I'd be glad to help offline (within the limits of NDA's, etc.) if you need it.